# Access: cannot move to next record with the code

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub btn_Next_Click()
'Creating Connection to database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Author"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        While (Not rs.EOF)
            Me.txtID = rs.Fields("Author_id")
            Me.txtFName = rs.Fields("AFirst_Name")
            Me.txtLName = rs.Fields("ALast_Name")
            Me.txtAddress = rs.Fields("Address")
            Me.txtEAddress = rs.Fields("Email_Address")
            Me.txtMNum = rs.Fields("Mobile_Number")
            Me.txtPNum = rs.Fields("Phone_Number")
            Me.cmbStatus = rs.Fields("Status")
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly do you need? Posting code is not enough to guess what is your problem.

Comment: I have a table Author -> i created a form author -> In this form i have navigation buttons, one of the button is Next- to navigate to the next record.
i wrote this piece of code to move it to the next record, but it moves directly to one record before the last one and stops, it doesn't go further.

Comment: Your code loads the recordset and then immediately traverses to the end. You are not moving through the active records based on a user action.

Comment: Then how should it be ??

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. i wrote the query based on the current record displayed in the form, then no need of a loop, every time you click on next, it gets the next value from the database and post it in the textboxes.